# How to get a lower resolution version of an image from Wikimedia

Tags: url, uri, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to be able to fetch Wikimedia's images, selecting a custom (or lower) resolution than the default's one.

I've found an [image that says that it should be possible by changing the URL](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:You_can_change_the_size_of_images_uploaded_to_wikipedia_by_changing_the_url.png), however, It doesn't work.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other solution using publicly accessible URI?

Some of the ones I tested:

- Full res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/DNA_Overview2_crop.png
- Half res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/DNA_Overview2_crop.png/200px-DNA_Overview2_crop.png
- Full res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Fotothek_df_n-06_0000001.jpg
- Half res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Fotothek_df_n-06_0000001.jpg/200px-Fotothek_df_n-06_0000001.jpg
- Full res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg
- Half res: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg/200px-Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg.png

As you can see, none of them work. Is there any other method or a way to do it properly with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method works if you use "thumb" in the url after "commons/".

So, the low resolution of this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg

becomes this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg/200px-Mount_St._Helens_erupting_blue.jpg.png